# How do game devs tie physics to fps?

Tags: physics, graphics, performance

If a GPU is rendering 3D graphics, doesn't it have to wait for the CPU to finish computing all the physics calculations before returning a frame? And if it does have to do that, then how does game development tie physics to fps?

Comment: Also note that the GPU can be used to compute some parts of physics pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that there's a sequential dependency between physics/gameplay updates and rendering.

The usual structure here is a [Game Loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html), where we run through a sequence of steps like...

1. Read input
2. Tick gameplay sim forward one time step (or more, if the sim is currently behind)
3. Prepare draw commands to visualize the latest game state
4. Send those draw commands to the GPU
5. (Optional: wait for the time to start working on the next frame)
6. Return to 1

However, this does not necessarily mean we keep the GPU waiting in steps 1-3. We can pipeline our frames, so as soon as we issue the draw commands for one frame, we're already working on computing the gameplay state for the next frame while the GPU is busy rendering, and we can have fresh draw commands ready for it to pick up as soon as it's done. So both CPU and GPU can often be working in parallel, despite the sequential dependency.

When we tick the game simulation, we're typically calling a function like "Update" and passing it a delta time variable, representing the (fractional) amount of in-game seconds to advance the state by. Given the previous state and the delta time, we can compute the next state something like:

```
newPosition = oldPosition + velocity * deltaTime
```

(Of course this gets more complicated for more complex mechanics like collision resolution, but the basic idea is the same)

The delta time variable can be measured based on the time the last frame took to fully process, so we know how much time we have to account for in the next pass. But having a time delta that changes from tick to tick can make some calculations less deterministic and reliable, so for consistency many games prefer to use a fixed time step. They choose in advance some constant simulation step size, and then run multiple steps back-to-back when they need to catch up to a measured time delta longer than a single step. We have lots of Q&A getting into the nitty gritty of this, if you'd like to learn more.